# Very strange error in Java

Tags: java

When I try to run my program java shows me

```
at gridControl.<init>(gridControl.java:3)
at game.<init>(game.java:4)
```

it repeats these line so much that I cant see the top of the error message.

the two lines that it is pointing to are:

```
Game.java:4 : gridControl Grid = new gridControl();
gridControl.java:3 : game Game = new game();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show proper stacktrace

Comment: You have a problem with your `gridControl`.

Comment: `game Game = new game();` ?? RIP naming conventions.

Comment: You probably have stack overflow problem. You may recursively call constructors, so the stack ends.

Comment: as suresh stated, please stick to the Java naming conventions (Class names start with an UpperCase and everything else with a lowerCase). theyre not optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, Game.java on line 4 instigates a new gridcontrol.
However, you can also see that gridControl.java on line 3 instigates a new Gamecontrol.
So basically you end up with a recursive infinite loop of: "New game -> New Grid -> New Game -> New Grid" and so on..

Answer (score 0):

DusteD is correct.

To get the full stack trace, redirect the output (stdout and stderr) to a file:`java -cp classes my.package.Main > game.log 2>&1`

You'll probably see a stack-overflow error in there that is caused by the recursive instantiation of gridControl and game.